# Regularity and the Varitational Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $K = \left\{ v \in H_0^1(\Omega) \, : \, v \geq 0 \right\}$, further suppose $\Omega$ has the regularity property that $||v||_{H^2} \leq C(\Omega)||\Delta v||_{L^2}$, for all $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. So far I've shown $u\in K$ and it satisfies the variational inequality but I need to show that $u \in H^2$?

Comment: The variational inequality satisfied is $\int \nabla u \cdot (\nabla v - \nabla u) \geq \int f(v-u)$ $\forall v \in K$

Answer (score 1):

This result can be found in [a paper by Brezis and Stampacchia](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1968__96__153_0), see in particular Theorem II.1.
They prove under rather weak assumptions (in your case: $f \in L^2(\Omega)$), that $-\Delta u \in L^2(\Omega)$.
This, in turn, gives you $u \in H^2(\Omega)$.